# wild cards with super behaving strangely

Tags: java, generics

```
ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
 numbers.add(1); 
 numbers.add(2.3);
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(1.2, 3.4, 46.7);
    copy(numbers, doubles);

    public <T> void copy(List<? super T> destination, List<? extends T> source) {
            for (T s : source) {
                destination.add(s); **// this working fine.**
            }
            System.out.println(destination);
        }
```

The above code works. But below code dosen't works why ?
Below I'm clearing saying to the compiler the Type is Integer type.

```
List<? super Integer> superInteger = Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3);
        superInteger.add(6); **//this will not give compile time errors but throw unsupportedexception**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the wildcards or `super` keyword. `Arrays#asList` method returns a fixed sized list. You can't add or remove into them. If you want to mutate the list, you've to create a new list.

```
List<? super Integer> superInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
superInteger.add(6);   // Now its fine
```